# Resize image inside pdf without streaming it (pdfbox)

Tags: java, pdfbox

I´m having some problems extracting pdf to image (png). I was getting some OOM errors [has already checked all possible issues that are in pdfbox´s FAQ about oom errors] so i decided to create a check before the conversion. Like this:

```
private static boolean checkPDFImagesSize(PDDocument document) {
PDPageTree list = document.getPages();
PDXObject o;
for (PDPage page : list) {
    PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
    for (COSName cosName : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
         try {
             o = pdResources.getXObject(cosName);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.info(e.toString());
            }
            if (o instanceof org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject) {
                if (((PDImageXObject) o).getHeight() * ((PDImageXObject) o).getWidth() * ((PDImageXObject) o)
                        .getBitsPerComponent() * 3.0 > ALERT_IMAGE_SIZE_INSIDE_PDF) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically what i do here is try to "guess" extrapolating the value that´s is going to be necessary to stream and create the image. If it´s bigger than ALERT_IMAGE_SIZE_INSIDE_PDF, i return false and a message is shown to the user.

My problem is that user is complaining about this aproach. What i needed to know was if it is possible to resize the image inside the pdf (without streaming it). I tried the PDImageXObject.setHeight but the image size doesn´t work. Is there any other aproach to this problema!?

pdf exemple:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13RIPcjj4EghOCcNSggUDcSaeUeqdqaZD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share an example pdf which produces such an oom?

Comment: due to some limitations my jvm has a -Xmx1024m limit. And here is a file which "eats" all jvmmemory.

Comment: If you are doing large bitmap image manipulations (in the case at hand a 5444x4083x24 JPEG), you have to provide enough memory if standard image manipulation is used, but that might account for probably 150 MB in your example, not more. It is not clear where the rest of the 1024 MB go. For an analysis of that you'd have to provide more information on what your program does how. If the remaining memory fottprint cannot be reduced, you'd need to employ a different graphics library which predominantly caches to disk instead of using much main memory.

Comment: That´s my exactly my problema. Despite the 1024Mb my memory footprint is high and i cannot reduce it. Can you enlight me about using a diferente graphic lybrary with cache on disk and provide me with a similar exemple to mine. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot; I don't know whether there is such a library, it merely is obvious that you need one. You probably even have to implement it yourself. That being said you ought to consider reducing memory requirements in other parts of your application, too.